# how to create installer for my application in linux

Tags: java, installation

I created a java application(jar files) and want to install package for my application with following items:

1. jre1.7.9
2. mysql
3. my fonts

how to create a installer for my app Which is available on all Linux distributions?

Answer (score 2):

may be you can execute a .jar file from the terminal. this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101746/how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-from-the-terminal) can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Download [izpack](http://izpack.org/downloads/) from 
run IzPack-install.jar. there should be jdk installed on your pc.
After installation open folder where it is installed.

See this [tutorial](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=89).